# Tooltip not displaying in ng-bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to use ng-bootstrap(1.1.0) with Angular(5.2.0) and bootstrap(4.0). Although i have imported all specific modules, I am unable to display the tooltip. Below is my code:

app.module.ts:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

component.html:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
     placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="Tooltip text">Hover over me
   </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Anybody please help me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `BrowserModule` and `NgModule` to your app.

This is how your `app.module.ts` should look:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, NgbModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks but I already imported these and all other required modules. Is there an issue with ng-bootstrap version.

Comment: No, I have installed ng-bootstrap v.1.1.0 and it still works. Here is a Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnuhby?file=package.json